# "Заждіть" - нормативне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів

В українських словниках є слова ***"чекати"*** та ***"ждати"***, які є синонімами.

> **[Ждати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhdaty)** 1. перех. Перебувати де-небудь, щоб побачити когось, зустрітися з кимось; чекати, очікувати.
>
> **[Чекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/chekaty)** 1. перех., кого, чого, що, на кого — що і без додатка. Перебувати де-небудь, щоб побачити когось, зустрітися з кимсь;
>   розраховувати на появу, прихід кого-, чого-небудь; ждати.

**[Словник синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53398/264643.html)**

> ***ЖДАТИ***  (на кого) ***чекати***, очікувати, дожидати <сподіватися> кого; ФР. вижидати, вичікувати; (з лихим наміром) чатувати, чигати; п!
>   ЧЕКАТИ, СТРИВАТИ.

Також в СУМ-11 присутнє

> **[Почекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochekaty)** **1.** Чекати якийсь час. **2.** наказ. сп. почекай, почекайте. Уживається як застереження або нахваляння, погроза.

Як бути із словом [***"заждіть"***](https://mymemory.translated.net/ru/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C), яке так широко вживається в значені "почекайте", але відсутнє в словниках. Чи нормативне слово ***"заждіть"***?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Слово *заждіть* не шукатиметься в словниках, оскільки не є словарною формою, а спонукальним чи [наказовим](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C). Для цього потрібно [інфінітив](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#%D0%92_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) — початковий вид дієслова, котрим є *заждати*.

| *Інфінітив* | зажда́ти | зажда́ть |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Наказовий спосіб | *однина* | *множина* |
| *1 особа* | — | зажді́мо, зажді́м |
| *2 особа* | зажди́ | **зажді́ть** |
| МАЙБУТНІЙ ЧАС | *однина* | *множина* |
| *1 особа* | зажду́ | заждемо́, зажде́м |
| *2 особа* | зажде́ш | заждете́ |
| *3 особа* | зажде́ | зажду́ть |
| МИНУЛИЙ ЧАС | *однина* | *множина* |
| *чоловічий рід* | зажда́в | зажда́ли |
| *жіночий рід* | зажда́ла | 〃 |
| *середній рід* | зажда́ло | 〃 |

Слово *заждати* шукається в усіх відомих мені словниках: СУМ в [11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zazhdaty)/[20](//services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29205&page=966) книгах, [Грінченка, Кримського тощо](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&highlight=on).

Висновок: слово є **нормативним**, але деякі словники, до прикладу обидва СУМ, чомусь позначають його як *розмовним*.

Answer (score -2):

> Мовна норма (від лат. norma – правило, взірець) – це сукупність мовних засобів,
> які в конкретному мовному колективі на певному історичному етапі вважаються
> правильними й зразковими.

[джерело](https://miyklas.com.ua/p/ukrainska-mova/10-klas/poniattia-normi-v-suchasnii-ukrayinskii-literaturnii-movi-326692/normativne-i-nenormativne-movlennia-tipi-norm-leksichna-norma-326143/re-0853b91e-6188-4000-ad91-5a7047fec886)

На даному історичному етапі, слово *ждати* і всі похідні від нього я б не назвав нормативними, оскільки маємо більш милозвучне, зразкове (з точки зору більшості авторитетних друкованих/ТБ/радіо та ін. джерел) і частіше вживане слово *чекати*.
Загалом, є багато прикладів слів з ідентичним значенням, на мою думку, наявність двох версій лише додають плутанини, тому варто надавати перевагу одній версії. Іншим прикладом є ступені порівняння *краще* і *ліпше*. Ніби обидва слова є в словниках, але одне явно зайве.

Comment: Якщо метою є скласти мінімалістичний словник (наприклад є розділ Вікіпедії https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page написаний на Basic English, словник якого має 850 слів), або словник юридичних термінів, тоді має сенс певні слова називати "зайвими". Але в інших випадках синонімія є ознакою багатства мови, як наприклад про це пише мовознавець Олександр Пономарів: http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/synonimy

Comment: @Artemix, дякую за коментар, багато нового дізнався, поки шукав аргументи на свою користь.